# How to retrieve token from script

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, strava

I have the following script:

```
let url = window.location.href;

const token = {
    authorization(url){
        authentication_code =  url.split("?")[1].split("&")[1].split("=")[1];
        this.postData("https://www.strava.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=3035dd7&client_secret=3db4fddd039117f8029b406fe72669a4472594bfb6b&code=" + authentication_code)
            .then(data =>  data.access_token) // JSON-string from `response.json()` call
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    },
    postData(url = "") {
        return fetch(url, {
            method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached   

        })  
            .then(response => response.json()); // parses response to JSON  

    }   
};
```

This script should authorize a client to strava and retrieve a token for further usage. Somehow I'm not able to understand how to get the token out of the const token.

when I call token.authorization(). It will authorize. But I have no idea how to retrieve the data.access_token from the function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple return statement could be used before this.postData and you would send the token in the promise.

```
let url = window.location.href;

const token = {
authorization(url){
    authentication_code =  url.split("?")[1].split("&")[1].split("=")[1];
    return this.postData("https://www.strava.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=3035dd7&client_secret=3db4fddd039117f8029b406fe72669a4472594bfb6b&code=" + authentication_code)
        .then(data =>  data.access_token) // JSON-string from `response.json()` call
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
},
postData(url = "") {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached   

    })  
        .then(response => response.json()); // parses response to JSON  

}   
};
```

and when calling, you get a promise in return with the token, so

```
token.authorization(url).then(tokenFromResponse=>console.log(tokenFromResponse));
```

Now you can use the token as desired.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering: once I have the token. What should I do with it in order to use it for further request? Amy suggestion or reads about best practices? I guess store as cookie...  it I’m looking for examples.

Comment: The way we do it is by saving the token into localStorage, and reading it whenever we need it. If you are using Angular/React app, you could implement a store (@ngrx/store for Angular or Redux(I think it is called that, I haven't worked on react) for React )

Comment: I started working on this. But I don't totally get it. How do I get the TOKEN in a variable? like:  let json = loadToken(tokenurl).then(tokenFromResponse=>tokenFromResponse.access_token);

I would like to use the token for the next API call. Any suggestions? how this work?

 let json = loadToken(tokenurl).then(tokenFromResponse=>tokenFromResponse.access_token);
 
};

async function loadToken(url) { // (1)
  let response = await fetch(url,{method: "POST"}); // (2)

  if (response.status == 200) {
    let json = await response.json(); // (3)
    return json;
  }